# Menu is null when activity gets recreated

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have inflated the action bar menu in the base activity and modifying the action bar items in  my base activity. But When i change the orientation, menu is always null and thats why it doesn't update my action bar items. Why it null?
Here is my tried code:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.base, menu);
        mMenu = menu;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // switch (item.getItemId()) {

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_refresh) {
            refreshNewsData();
            return true;
        }
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_share) {
            sharenewsData();

            return true;
        }
        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_favorite) {
            addFavorites();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
```

I have written this code in base activity. 
protected void showIcons(int id) {

```
if (mMenu != null) {

            MenuItem item = mMenu.findItem(id);
            item.setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    protected void hideIcons(int id) {
        if (mMenu != null) {

            MenuItem item = mMenu.findItem(id);
            item.setVisible(false);
        }
```

I'm using these methods to update the action bar menu items

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update ActionBar Menu items directly. Whenever you want to update menu items, make a call to `invalidateOptionsMenu()` this'll redraw the action bar menus and will make a call to `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. You'll have to take care of the menu items you want to show / hide inside `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`.

Comment: where should i call invalidateOptionsMenu?is it inside on create of baseActivity or onCreate of MainActivity? And Cant i write those methods-showIcons & hideIcons

Comment: I guess, you extend your base activity in all yout activities ? Then in that case, the change will happen in all the activities where you extend base activity. If you just want the changes in one particular activity, add the hide/show methods inside that activity only. You can use the hide and show methods but make sure you call them from onPrepareOptionsMenu()

Comment: means I should write those methods inside onPrepareoption menu?But how to call them from inside this method..I wrote those methods inside base activity..N I'm calling them directly whenever i need it

Comment: how to call them inside onPRepare options menu

Comment: directly make a call ?

Comment: i didn't get it...U mean i should define those methods inside onPrepare options and I can call them directly?

Comment: No, if you've defined your methods in the base class, you'll be able to make calls to it from anywhere.

Comment: but u said i should call them inside onPrepareOptions menu?

Comment: yes, so call the method from inside onPrepareOptionsMenu()

Comment: can u give me a sample..because I'm not able to follow..how can i call it from inside onPrepareOptions menu...I need to make changes in fragments